# Как подключить метод чтобы вызвать его в другом классе Java?

Tags: java

Существует 5 классов: один основной с объектами, в классе ball существует логическая конструкция соответствии с которой результат всех действий будет выведен на консоль, остальные классы ссылаются на ball. Вопрос: как подключить метод tryRun и вызвать его в других классах? (схема сказки "Колобок").

Метод 1

```
public class Ball {

    public void tryRun(boolean condition) {
        if (condition){
            System.out.println("the ball is eaten!");
        } else{
            System.out.println("the ball escaped!");
        }
    }
}
```

Метод 2

```
public class Hare {
    public void tryEat(Ball ball) {
        public void tryBall(true false){

        }
    }
}
```

Метод 3

```
public class Wolff {
    public void tryEat(Ball ball) {
        public void tryBall(true false){

        }
    }
}
```

Метод 4

```
public class Fox {
    public void tryEat(Ball ball) {
        public void tryBall() {
            System.out.println(this.condition);
        }
    }
}
```

Основной метод

```
public class BallStory {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ball ball = new Ball();
        Hare hare = new Hare();
        Wolff wolff = new Wolff();
        Fox fox = new Fox();
        hare.tryEat(ball);
        wolff.tryEat(ball);
        fox.tryEat(ball);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 0):

У вас две ошибки, из-за которых код не будет работать. Первая ошибка - функция не может быть определена внутри функции, переделайте подобным образом:

```
public class Hare {
    public void tryEat(Ball ball) {

    }
    public void tryBall(true false) {

    }
}
```

Вторая ошибка - в качестве параметров функции могут быть только переменные, что вы хотели сделать в этой строке?

```
public void tryBall(true false) {

}
```

По поводу вашего вопроса - вы можете передавать объект колобка в метод другого объекта (например, кролика), после чего вызывать метод колобка в методе другого класса. Попробуйте так:

*Hare.java*

```
public class Hare {
    public void tryEat(Ball ball) {
        ball.tryRun(true);
    }
    public void tryBall() {
        
    }
}
```

*BallStory.java*

```
public class BallStory {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ball ball = new Ball();
        Hare hare = new Hare();
        hare.tryEat(ball);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам больное! Несколько дней голову ломал (я новичок).

Comment: @Umnik На здоровье :) Если у вас всё прекрасно заработало, можете тогда отметить мой ответ, как решение?